# How to send images from Flask to JavaScript in real time

Tags: python, html, opencv, webrtc

I'm currently writing a program that uses webRTC, Flask, and openCV etc... to analyze a webcam video in real time.
I succeeded in sending the webcam video from JavaScript to the Flask server, but I cannot display the image after analysis from Flask to HTML.

For example, I tried to save the image file once.

```py
@app.route("/img", methods=["POST"])
def img():
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(request.files['video'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

　　 #Processing by openCV...

    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg", img)
    return "success"

@app.route('/feed')
def feed():
    return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def gen():
    while True:
        with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            img = f.read()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img + b'\r\n')
```

Next is the HTML code

```html
<img id="cap-src" src="{{ url_for('feed') }}">
```

However, this code curiously didn't update the image displayed in HTML, so I gave up.

Then I tried the method of not saving the image.

```py
@app.route("/img", methods=["POST"])
def img():
    global img
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(request.files['video'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

def generate_img():
　　#Processing by openCV...

@app.route('/feed')
def feed():
    return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def gen():
    while True:
        img = generate_img()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img + b'\r\n')
```

The HTML code does not change.
However, this method did not update the image displayed in HTML.
Is there any good way? 
And I want to use a method that doesn't save the image if possible.Thank you.

Finally, I put the summarized code.
This is the HTML code

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img">
<video id="myvideo" width="720px" autoplay></video>
<button id="start"></button>
<canvas id="videocanvas"></canvas>
<img id="cap-src" src="">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    const constraints = window.constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: {
        facingMode: "environment"
      }
    };

    async function init() {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        const video = document.querySelector('#myvideo');
        const videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
        window.stream = stream;
        video.srcObject = stream;
        e.target.disabled = true;
      } catch{
        $('#errorMsg').text('error');
      }
    }

    $('#start').click(init);

    var canvas = $('#videocanvas')[0];

 $('#myvideo').on('loadedmetadata', function(){
     var video = $('#myvideo')[0];
     var width = canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
     var height = canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

     var fd = new FormData();
     fd.append('video', null);

     setInterval(function(){
         ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
         canvas.toBlob(function(blob){

             fd.set('video', blob);

             $.ajax({
                 url: "/img",
                 type : "POST",
                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 data : fd,
                 dataType: "text",
             })
             .done(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
             })
             .fail(function(data){
                 console.log(data);
             });
         }, 'image/jpeg');
     },100);
 });
});

document.getElementById("start").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("cap-src").src = "{{ url_for('feed') }}";

  }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the python code.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, request, jsonify
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST') # Put any other methods you need here
    return response

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/img", methods=["POST"])
def img():
    img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(request.files['video'].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    image = cv2.resize(img, (480, 300))
    cv2.imwrite("test.jpg", image)
    ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    jpeg = jpeg.tobytes()

    return "success"

@api.route('/feed')
def feed():
    return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

def gen():
    while True:
        with open('./templates/dst/test.jpg', 'rb') as f:
            img = f.read()

        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + img + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: Quick question, in the method that you are saving the video file. Have you tried embedding the path to your video file in your html template inside a video tag? Also are you following this tutorial?https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

Comment: Yes, I tried that method. It worked, but preferably I don't want to save the image. I am following a tutorial.

Comment: Hey, @Akari , what is the output of print(type(img))

Comment: The output is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.

Comment: If you have git repository of the project I would like to clone it and try to debug on my end? @Akari

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't created a git repository for this project. However, I added the current python code and HTML code to the question. There is no other code, this is the big picture. It can be used with the command "flask run". I would be happy if you could help me.

Comment: unfortunately I have not been able to run the code you have provided. From looking at the code what you are trying to achieve is two video streams client side, one of them being the original video feed the other being a modified video feed. I highly reccomend using opencv.js to achieve this. Take a look at this example https://docs.opencv.org/master/js_face_detection_camera.html

Comment: I'm sorry. Due to circumstances, OpenCV.js cannot be used, so I decided to use BytesIO to solve the problem.Thanks for your advice!

Comment: if you have found a solution to your own problem, feel free to add it in the answer yourself. I would personally be intrested in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue you mentioned is about "displaying the image after analysis from Flask to HTML", so here is the solution to your problem, it can send video or camera output images to the html. For more details follow this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/2Nw4WQj4isA)

The main python app (which will run on the server) file is here:

### app.py

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,Response
import cv2,imutils,time
import pyshine as ps
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
   return render_template('index.html')

def changeBrightness(img,value):
    """ This function will take an image (img) and the brightness
        value. It will perform the brightness change using OpenCv
        and after split, will merge the img and return it.
    """
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)
    lim = 255 - value
    v[v>lim] = 255
    v[v<=lim] += value
    final_hsv = cv2.merge((h,s,v))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv,cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    return img

def changeBlur(img,value):
    """ This function will take the img image and blur values as inputs.
        After perform blur operation using opencv function, it returns
        the image img.
    """
    kernel_size = (value+1,value+1) # +1 is to avoid 0
    img = cv2.blur(img,kernel_size)
    return img

def pyshine_process(params):
    print("Parameters:",params)
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    CAMERA=True
    if CAMERA:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    else:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/mario.mp4')
    print('FUNCTION DONE')
    # Read until video is completed
    fps=0
    st=0
    frames_to_count=20
    cnt=0


    while(cap.isOpened()):

        ret, img = cap.read()
        brightness_value_now = int(params['brightness'])
        blur_value_now = int(params['blur'])
        img = changeBrightness(img,brightness_value_now)
        img = changeBlur(img,blur_value_now)
        if ret == True:

            if cnt == frames_to_count:
                try: # To avoid divide by 0 we put it in try except

                    fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                    st = time.time()
                    cnt=0
                except:
                    pass

            cnt+=1

            img = imutils.resize(img, width=640)

            text  =  'FPS: '+str(fps)
            img = ps.putBText(img,text,text_offset_x=20,text_offset_y=30,background_RGB=(10,20,222))
            text = str(time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H.%M.%S %p"))
            img = ps.putBText(img,text,text_offset_x=190,text_offset_y=30,background_RGB=(228,20,222))
            text  =  f"Brightness: {brightness_value_now}"
            img = ps.putBText(img,text,text_offset_x=20,text_offset_y=300,background_RGB=(20,210,4))
            text  =  f'Blur: {blur_value_now}'
            img = ps.putBText(img,text,text_offset_x=490,text_offset_y=300,background_RGB=(210,20,4))
            frame = cv2.imencode('.JPEG', img,[cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY,20])[1].tobytes()
            time.sleep(0.016)
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
        else:
            break


@app.route('/res',methods = ['POST','GET'])
def res():
    global result
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form.to_dict()
        return render_template("results.html",result = result)

@app.route('/results')
def video_feed():
    global result
    params= result
    return Response(pyshine_process(params),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='192.168.1.104',port=9999,threaded=True)
```

Here are the files for the templates folder

#### index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PyShine streaming video application </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please input the parameters (0 to 100): </h1>
    <form action = "http://192.168.1.104:9999/res" method = "POST">
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Brightness:</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" name="brightness" value="1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Blur:</td>
          <td align="left"><input type="text" name="blur" value="0" /></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### results.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>PyShine Streaming Video Application </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PyShine streaming processed video... </h1>
        <br>
        <img src="">
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Go back!" onclick="history.back()">  
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Important: change the host IP address according to your specifications.